# gem install json fails with redifinition of struct timezone/timespec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, compiler-errors, rubygems

I am on Windows with Ruby 1.9.3 with DevKit (all 32 bit on Win 7 64 bit). Now I try to install rails, but get an error from bundle. If I try to run (what bundle is complaining about)

```
 gem install json
```

I get the following error message:

```
D:\RubyTest>gem install json
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        D:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
In file included from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381:0,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:41:8: error: redefinition of 'struc
t timespec'
In file included from d:\ruby193\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../
../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:62,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:223,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
d:\ruby193\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-ming
w32/include/sys/types.h:89:8: note: originally defined here
In file included from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381:0,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:48:8: error: redefinition of 'struc
t timezone'
In file included from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:63:0,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:223,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from d:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
d:\ruby193\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-ming
w32/include/time.h:260:8: note: originally defined here
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.
7 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3 was compiled with GCC 4.5.2, which is DevKit `DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe` available from [RubyInstaller's download page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads)

You downloaded the newer DevKits, that are **only** compatible with Ruby 2.0.0 release, as indicated in RubyInstaller announcement.

To clarify:

- Ruby 1.8.7: `tdm-32-4.5.2`
- Ruby 1.9.2: `tdm-32-4.5.2`
- Ruby 1.9.3: `tdm-32-4.5.2`
- Ruby 2.0.0: `mingw64-32-4.7.2` (and 64bits version for 64bits Ruby)

I've added a clarification to RubyInstaller download page about this.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thats exactly the solution. I think this is worth putting on the RubyInstaller's download page! :) Thank you!

Comment: Exactly, this bit me too. I downloaded the mingw64 version based on the fact that it was much newer.

Comment: Same thing here - json 1.7.7 compiles now without a problem!

Comment: I've added this to the download page, right column, at the top of everything :-D

Comment: I think the best place would be on the download list. Something like RUBY 2+: <mingw downloads>, RUBY <= 1.9.3: <tdm download>

Comment: @FrontierPsycho this is reflected already in the download page under *What version of DevKit to download*.

Comment: I know, but it's extremely easy to just erroneously grab the 'latest one' and not read the right column at all. This way, people will always grab the correct one. I commented on the _place_ it is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can open "win32.h" found in the *include* directory fo your ruby version.

Then comment out the lines where the "clock_gettime" "clock_getres" functions are declared.