# Rails on windows - install issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm trying to install ruby on a Windows box and am having an issue. I have gotten up to this point when I start getting errors, and I'm completely new to anything other than PHP for web development. Help appreciated!

*EDIT* I'm following the instructions here for wamp:

http://www.alexbernard.fr/fichiers/blog/Installer-Ruby-On-Rails-sur-un-Wamp-Server.pdf

```
./gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

Output:

```
INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed
INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        C:/wamp/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
make
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127
Gem files will remain installed in C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Using rails with wamp is a mistake. If you're doing development you should be using built-in webrick or similar. If you're doing production you should be using linux.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the output shown above, I assume the following:

- Installed Ruby 2.0.0 x64 (64bits)
- Installed *some* DevKit from RubyInstaller page

Now, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123048/117298), for 64bits Ruby you need 64bits DevKit.

From the error in the output:

`make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found`

It is clear you didn't install the right DevKit.

Please remove the DevKit installed, download the correct one (as indicated in the link above and in [RubyInstaller downloads page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads)) and install again.

You will require to use `ruby dk.rb install --force` (note the `--force` option) to override the previous DevKit installation.

As for the the deprecation error, `--include-dependencies` is no longer required. I recommend you use as installation reference a modern Ruby/Rails guide.

Comment: Is it possible to have two DevKit installations (32bit and 64bit) side by site? I have both 32bit and 64bit Ruby installed which I switch between for testing. But I can only get one to install compiled gems at a time - the one where I installed matching DevKit for last.

Comment: @thomthom eg. Install 32bits Ruby to `C:\Ruby200` and 64bits to `C:\Ruby200-x64`, then place DevKit in similar way: `C:\DevKit\4.7.2-32` and `C:\DevKit\4.7.2-64`, edit `config.yml` of each one to point to right Ruby installation.

Comment: That's what I did. Hm... I'll try again fresh and file an issue at GitHub if problem persist.

Comment: @LuisLavena - Thanks for the post. But, this did not work for me. I have ruby 2.0.0 x64 from Ruby installer. Devkkit - DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe. I even installed mingw with the base and developer packages. I am stuck where I started. I have no choice but to do this on a Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent two days trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 5):

You can go the [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) way to install Rails and all dependencies in one go without getting into such problems.

Comment: Do you know how that plays with wamp?

Comment: I'm not sure, but chances are you'd be able to use phusion passenger to deploy to apache.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the problem was that the DevKit binaries did not get added to the PATH.  Make sure that (DEVKIT_FOLDER)\mingw\bin is on the path.

Answer (score 0):

Because I read this answer with hope of fixing my problem, and found it did not help, here's how I resolved it:

--

Your error is:

`make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found`

--

The error means that [you don't have access to the `gcc/gc++` compiler](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/MinGW/Tutorial) on your PC.

You should therefore either locate, or download a version of the compiler to your system. I found [installing the build tools located here](http://win-builds.org/doku.php/download_and_installation_from_windows) solved the issue.

You just have to download those tools, then add them to the PATH var: `set PATH=C:/path/to/your/ming64/location/;%PATH%;`

This should build it for you.

A caveat -- whether you have the correct dependencies for a build to take place is another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The exe is in rubydevkit\mingw\bin.  Just add that to your path and json will build.