# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, devkit

I'm getting the below error while installing '`redcarpet`' gem. It got installed without issue on my friends machine though. (I want to install this to run `yard`)
Ruby version: 1.9.3

**cmd output:**

```
D:\Learning\Common_POM_FW\SampleProjects>yard
[error]: Missing 'redcarpet' gem for Markdown formatting. Install it with `gem install redcarpet`

D:\Learning\Common_POM_FW\SampleProjects>gem install redcarpet
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing redcarpet:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141009-6544-978w4t.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redcarpet-3.1.2 for inspectio
n.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/redcarpet-3.1.2/gem_ma
ke.out
```

**UPDATE:**
With the devkit installation instructions provided at https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit When I test the installation with json gem it fails there too :(

I went through the link for troubleshoot in github [Native gem extension Error](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) and followed the instructions to solve, Yet the problem persists..

I added the two paths to Env var `C:\\ruby_devkit\\bin;C:\\ruby_devkit\\mingw\\bin;` This removes the line `Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...` from appearing on cmd

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally after much research I found the culprit was the RubyGems version incompatibility with native extension gems!!!

I had ruby gems ver 2.4.1 but seems like >2.4.0 has these issues

`gem update --system 2.3.0` did the trick for me :)

Refer: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977

Comment: Hero! I tried about 37 solutions...  38th time lucky!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much

Comment: This advice totally damage my ruby installation! It is not possible to upgrade to the latest gem now, neither it helps to fix the issue.

Comment: For me, simply updating using `gem update --system` fixed the issue. **DONT** downgrade, it will **NOT** fix the issue!

Answer (score 6):

Downgrading ruby gems didn't work for me.

What did work was (with the latest version of ruby gems installed):

Open CMD as administrator and...

```
gem install json --platform=ruby --verbose
```

(Answer added by [dannysmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1904855/dannysmith) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688671/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-on-windows-7-the-system-cannot-find-the))