# Cannot update Calabash-sandbox Ruby "no implicit conversion of nil into String"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm fairly new to Calabash, and I've followed the tutorial on [Xamarins website](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/configuring/windows/calabash-sandbox/). Problem is, when running

```
PS C:\> (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/calabash/install/master/install-windows.ps1") | iex
```

it installs Ruby v. 2.1.6p336 which should be [incompatible with calabash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290426/error-installing-calabash-android-on-windows). Therefor I tried to update Ruby in PS with admin but it gives me this result:

```
[calabash] C:\>gem update --system 2.3.0
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-2.3.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

It also occurs outside of Calabash-sandbox.

Comment: Hopefully this helps you get an answer more quickly.  This doesn't have anything to do with calabash.  It's an error coming from the ruby gems framework.  I will edit the tags on the question so that it shows up in more searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an error while looking into your question for an edit.

There is a bug report here - https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1560 about errors when updating from some versions.  It has a workaround of specifying the version to update to.  So please could you try

```
gem update --system=2.6.6
```