# bundle install failing on JSON gem: Failing to build gem native extension, Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems, bundler

I'm upgrading development machines and so I'm in the process of getting my new machine up and running with my project from a repo. I install all needed software (Ruby, Devkits, etc), get the base gems installed (bundler, etc) and run `bundle install` in my project folder, producing this error:

```
> bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using multi_json 1.11.0
Using activesupport 3.2.21
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.21
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.3
Using actionpack 3.2.21
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.21
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.44
Using activerecord 3.2.21
Using activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 3.2.13
Using activeresource 3.2.21
Using authlogic 3.2.0
Using execjs 2.0.2

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Code/vampire_its/ios/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Code/vampire_its/ios/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've been researching solutions for a while now and attempted the suggested solution of running `gem install json --verbose`, which does indeed install the `json` gem correctly. However, it isn't properly added to my bundle without running `bundle install`. I even ran `bundler install --verbose` but that actually failed so I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on. I've actually tried with every single Ruby version I can get my hands on and every one produces the same error so it's starting to look like it's something on my machine, but I have no idea what.

Any help would be appreciated. Additional files/information will be included below

> Version Info

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 598) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => "C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

> Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.21'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3', '~>1.3.7'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
# Bundle the extra gems:
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

# Rake 0.9.1 breaks Rails
gem 'rake', '>=0.9.2'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
  gem 'factory_girl', '~> 2.5.0'
  gem 'rails-erd', '~>1.1.0', :require => false
  gem 'ruby_parser', '~>3.1.1', :require => false # seems to be an implicit dependency of rails-erd
  gem 'pry', '~>0.9.12.6'
  gem 'pry-rails', '~>0.2.2'
  gem 'pry-nav', '~>0.2.3'
  gem 'pry-doc', '~>0.5.1'
  gem 'xml-simple', '~> 1.1.4' 
end

gem "paperclip", "~>2.7.0"
gem "rubyzip", "~>0.9.9"

group :test do
  #gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.4'
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem "faker", '1.2.0'
  #gem "factory_girl", '~> 2.5.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'execjs', '~>2.0.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '~>1.3.0'
  gem "jquery-rails", '~>3.0.0'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'underscore-rails'
  gem "backbone-rails"
end

gem 'authlogic', '~>3.2.0'
gem "declarative_authorization", '~>0.5.6'
gem "sys-filesystem", '1.0.0'
gem "dynamic_form" , '~>1.1.4'
gem 'client_side_validations', '~>3.2.1'
gem "rest-client", '~>1.6.7', :require => "rest_client"
gem "httpclient"
gem 'd3-rails', '~>0.0.5'
gem 'bindata', '~>1.4.5'
gem 'eventmachine', '~>1.0.7', :require => false

if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
  #gem "geotrans", "0.0.1" , :path => '../geotrans/pkg/geotrans-0.0.1-x86_64-darwin-12'
elsif RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /(win|w)32$/
  gem "geotrans", "0.0.2" , :path => '../geotrans/pkg/geotrans-0.0.2-x86-mingw32'
end

gem "unit_conversion", :path => "./local-gems/unit_conversion"

# RGeo for geographic data support
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /(win|w)32$/
  gem 'rgeo', "0.3.14" , :path => '../rgeo/pkg/rgeo-0.3.14'
else
  gem 'rgeo', '~>0.3.14'
end

# SQL Server support
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~>3.2.10'

# test coverage
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.8/
   gem 'rcov', '~>1.0.0', :require => false, :group => :test
else
   gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
end

gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~>0.3.3'
gem "orderedhash", '~>0.0.6' # binary types uses this

gem "nokogiri", '~> 1.5.9'
gem "js-routes", '~> 0.8.8'
gem "numbers_and_words"
gem "gon", '~> 4.1.1'
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

> .bundle/config

```
---
BUNDLE_BIN: .bundle/bin
BUNDLE_PATH: .bundle/gems
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

> C:\Code\vampire_its\ios.bundle\gems\ruby\2.0.0\gems\json-1.8.2\ext\json\ext\generator\gem_make.out

```
C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

> bundle config

```
> bundle config
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
build.json
Set for the current user (C:/Users/Micah Cleveland/.bundle/config): "--version"

bin
Set for your local app (C:/Code/vampire_its/ios/.bundle/config): ".bundle/bin"

path
Set for your local app (C:/Code/vampire_its/ios/.bundle/config): ".bundle/gems"

disable_shared_gems
Set for your local app (C:/Code/vampire_its/ios/.bundle/config): "1"
```

Comment: It's not asking you to install with `--verbose` flag. It's asking you to install with the `-v` flag indicating the specific version of the json gem. Try installing running the full command: `gem install json -v '1.8.2'`

Comment: @MartinKonecny, I researched other people having the same problem and the suggested solution was using the `--verbose` tag. simply using `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` without the verbose flag produced the same error as `bundle install`. Trust me, i tried.

Comment: I'm not saying it will fix your problem. I'm saying it will help us diagnose what's wrong with that specific problematic version. Can you run `--verbose` along with the `-v '1.8.2'` flag

Comment: @MartinKonecny yes, that's how I successfully got it to install at all. the 1.8.2 version of the json gem is actually just the latest version of the gem. I didn't post the "successful" install because it's very, very long due to the `verbose` flag

Comment: Interesting - so just passing in the additional `--verbose` flag while not removing any others flags fixes the problem?

Comment: @MartinKonecny Right, at least when running `gem install`. `bundle install --verbose` actually doesn't fix the problem but that's because `json` is a dependency, i believe. See why I'm having trouble figuring this out? It's almost like my machine is moving too fast and the stdout printing slows it down enough to work which...seems really illogical

Comment: Maybe post the contents of `C:/Code/vampire_its/ios/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out` in your question as well.

Comment: @MartinKonecny It's done. It's literally a single line. Nothing useful.

Comment: Hmm, seems this is a bug in windows version of the `gem` command. Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22982031/276949 ? Or what about running the command prompt as admin user?

Comment: @MartinKonecny yes, I've tried both. That's where I first got my `--verbose` tag idea from actually. Didn't solve the bundler issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like passing in the `--version` flag to fix compilation is true bug, as [evidenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22982031/276949).

To mimic this behaviour in bundler we can use `bundle config`:

> You can use bundle config to give bundler the flags to pass to the gem installer every time bundler tries to install a particular gem.
>
> ...
>
> After running this command, every time bundler needs to install the mysql gem, it will pass along the flags you specified.

Try running

```
bundle config build.json --version
bundle install
```

This should cause bundler to run `gem install --verbose json`

Comment: `bundle config build.json --version` has no effect. Are we missing a step somewhere?

Comment: What's the output of `build config`?

Comment: I would a) report this issue to the rubygem issue tracker: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems b) in the meantime try reverting to an older version `gem update --system 2.0.3`. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the reverting thing as well :( ah well thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

if you run `gem install json --verbose -v '1.8.1'` you are going to see how the compiler is failing because it is not finding some C modules.

Seems to be that re-installing your current `ruby` version (with these `C` headers) might be a possible solution

checking your current ruby version

`ruby -v` => `ruby 2.5.8p224 (2020-03-31 revision 67882) [x86_64-darwin19]`

re-install ruby with C modules (with `rbenv`)

`CC=gcc rbenv install 2.5.8`