# Issue on install native extension ruby with windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, devkit

I'm troubled with installing a native gem on windows

`Error Could not Create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary`

I guess it's a version issue, because I've installed the dev kit for windows to use with ruby 2.0

my gem env is :

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
RUBY VERSION : 2.0.0 [x64-mingw32]
INSTALLATION DIR: C:/Ruby200-x64/bin
RUBYGEMS platforms:
- ruby 
- x64-mingw32
```

Comment: also execute devkit.vars to add to PATH

Comment: solved, fot those encountered the same issue, have a look on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579019/rails-on-windows-install-issue I have had installed a 32 bits dev kit version on 64 bits ruby system...