# Error installing json on windows 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed `rails 4.2.3` and `ruby 2.2.2p95` on `windows 8.1 x64` . When I try to run "bundle install" the installation fails because of `json -v 1.8.3`. I already have `json version 1.8.1` installed. When I run rubygems update command it does not get updated. If I try to individually run `gem install json -v 1.8.3` or `gem install json --platform=ruby --version=1.8.3` I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
invalid argument: -platform=ruby

C:\>gem install json --platform=ruby --version=1.8.3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150719-4308-1m86usl.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-        x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1
.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0
/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `gem install --verbose json -v 1.8.3`. This should install the gem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have the 32-bit DevKit installed instead. Try uninstalling the DevKit you have and downloading and re-installing the latest 64-bit one. For more detail check out this similar answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579088/4034665