# Why can't I install json -v '1.8.3' on Windows 10?

Tags: json, ruby, installation

When trying to install this gem, I receive the following:

```
Temporarily enhancing path to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161103-12844-13cqnmb.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

make "DESTDIR=" 
'make is not recognized as an  internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.

Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

---

The gem_make.out file is not in that folder. This is the last gem I need to install. What do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: This SO answer suggests trying `gem install --verbose json -v 1.8.3`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498908/error-installing-json-on-windows-8-1.  And FWIW, http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ states that "64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it. To use this version you will require some knowledge about compilers and solving dependency issues, which might be too complicated if you just want to play with the language."

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give it a try. I actually do need this for work, not just for playing. I may end up using my personal computer to do it, as it's on OSX.

Comment: orde, fortunately, this did work for me. Of course, now I've run into another issue, but so it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Nice that you got it worked out.  Worst comes to worst, post a new question for next issue that you run into :)