# Install json failed on windows

Tags: ruby, json

I got this issue when I install json by gem install on windows, and the error message is:

```
C:\DevKit>gem install json --platform=ruby --version=1.4.6
Fetching: json-1.4.6.gem (100%)Fetching: json-1.4.6.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ruby/re.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
generator.c:321:13: warning: 'fbuffer_free_only_buffer' defined but not used
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
c:/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt-ruby191
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.4.6 for    inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-    1.4.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

and whatis -lmsvcrt-ruby191, Is that a lib of ruby? From the error message it says cannot find -lmsvcrt-ruby191, that is arch-criminal?

I install json, because I want to make sure DevKit is installed successfully.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you try without "--platform=ruby --version=1.4.6", as well?

Comment: You can get the ideas from http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-05.html
AND
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121247/gem-install-json-fails-with-redifinition-of-struct-timezone-timespec